# Doubly Linked list not working properly, C

Tags: c, buffer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_item {
  int value;
  struct list_item *next;
  struct list_item *prev;
} list_item_t;

typedef struct single_list {
  list_item_t *head;
  list_item_t *tail;
} slist_t;

void init(slist_t *list) {
  list->head = NULL;
  list->tail = NULL;
}

void add(slist_t *list, int value) {
  list_item_t *newNode = (list_item_t *)malloc(sizeof(list_item_t));
  // Case for empty list
  if (list->head == NULL) {
      list->head = newNode;
      list->tail = newNode;
      newNode->value = value;
      newNode->prev = NULL;
      newNode->next = NULL;
  }
  // Case for nonempty list
  else {
      newNode->prev = list->tail;
      newNode->value = value;
      newNode->next = NULL;
      list->tail = newNode;
  }
}

void print(slist_t *list) {
  if (list->head == NULL) {
    printf("The list is empty\n");
    return;
  }
  list_item_t *currentNode = list->head;
  while (currentNode != NULL) {
    printf("%d ", currentNode->value);
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main() {
  slist_t myList;
  init(&myList);
  add(&myList, 5);
  add(&myList, 2);
  add(&myList, 6);
  print(&myList);
}
```

Ok I got rid of my bus error but now when I try to print my list all it prints out is:
1

Is the problem in init function or my add function? I was wondering if since I don't use malloc in the init function that the list gets erased after every function call of add? Is that true? I have tried allocating it like this:
    slist_t *list = (slist_t *)malloc(sizeof(slist_t))
but it gives me an error.

Comment: For one thing, you never change `list->tail` to point to the new tail...

Comment: You should check your `init` function again.

Comment: You list's tail is initialized to `NULL` and you dereference it.

Comment: init never uses its argument...

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: There are no compile errors, it just prints out 1 and not all the elements I'm adding

Answer (score 0):

Failing to link old tail's next to the new tail.

```
// Case for nonempty list
else {
  // Add.  `list->tail->next` should be NULL before this code.  
  list->tail->next = newNode;

  newNode->prev = list->tail;
  newNode->value = value;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  list->tail = newNode;
}
```